# Passing an external queue to flask route function?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to modify flask request callback so it can communicate with other code while executing the callback. The example explains it better:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from queue import Queue

flask_input_queue = Queue()
flask_output_queue = Queue()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    # The receiver on the other end gets notified we got a request
    flask_output_queue.put(str(request))

    # This blocks until the external party responds with something
    response = flask_input_queue.get()

    # But how do the queues end up in the function scope to begin with?
    return response


app.run(debug=True)
```

Here the external code would have a channel using the queues into the web server. This allows me to completely abstract the concept of the web server on the other part of the code.

However for that, I need to be able to pass information to the callback method in ways other that just URLs. Frankly it doesn't have to be a queue other IPC mechanisms will also work ok but they all rely on having a way to pass data into the callback.

Is there a way to do that in flask?

Answer (score 3):

The `_URLCallbackClass` in combination with `add_url_rule` is used instead of the decorator. That `_URLCallbackClass` gets the queue as instance attributes. Given that the actual callback function is the method of `_URLCallbackClass`, we smuggled the queues into the callback function.

The rest of the complexity just arises from providing a working example.

```
logging.basicConfig(format='[Thread: %(threadName)s-%(thread)d] %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)                                                                                                             [0/0]
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ControllableServer(threading.Thread):

    class _URLCallbackClass():
        def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue):
            self.input_queue = input_queue
            self.output_queue = output_queue

        def url_callback(self):
            self.output_queue.put("[URL callback] I just got called")
            response_from_the_queue = self.input_queue.get()
            return Response(response_from_the_queue, 200)

    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue
        self._flask = Flask(__name__)

    def run(self):
        callback_class = ControllableServer._URLCallbackClass(self.input_queue, self.output_queue)
        self._flask.add_url_rule('/endpoint', 'url_callback', callback_class.url_callback)
        logger.info(f"Starting flask")              
        self._flask.run()                           


def call_URL_in_separate_thread(url):               
    def call_URL(url):                              
        logger.info(f"Calling {url}")               
        response = requests.get(url)                
        logger.info(f"Got response: {response.text}")                                                    
        return response.text                        

    url_caller_thread = threading.Thread(target=call_URL, args=(url,))                                   
    url_caller_thread.start()                       


if __name__ == "__main__":                          
    flask_input_queue = Queue()                     
    flask_output_queue = Queue()                    
    controllable_server = ControllableServer(flask_input_queue, flask_output_queue)                      
    controllable_server.start()                     
    call_URL_in_separate_thread("http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint")                                        
    message_from_within_the_callback = flask_output_queue.get()                                          
    logger.info(f"Got message from queue: {message_from_within_the_callback}")                           
    message_to_the_callback = "I come from the outside !@##$@"                                           
    flask_input_queue.put(message_to_the_callback)  
    logger.info(f"Sending message to queue: {message_to_the_callback}")
```

Output:

```
[Thread: Thread-1-140465413375744] Starting flask
[Thread: Thread-2-140465404983040] Calling http://127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint
 * Serving Flask app "basic_flask_passing_variable" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[Thread: Thread-1-140465413375744]  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[Thread: MainThread-140465450415936] Got message from queue: [URL callback] I just got called
[Thread: MainThread-140465450415936] Sending message to queue: I come from the outside !@##$@
[Thread: Thread-3-140465396041472] 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2020 18:33:32] "GET /endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[Thread: Thread-2-140465404983040] Got response: I come from the outside !@##$@
```